# Page Method returns undefined response

Tags: asp.net, webforms, webmethod, pagemethods

I am using Visual Studio 2022 for a .NET 4.7.2 project.

I created a simple page to make use of web method it's not working for me. Even the breakpoint is not being hit in web method.

I get undefined as response.

Here is the code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="HouseRentalPortal.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
        <div>
            <button onclick="testmethod()">Test</button>
        </div>
        
    </form>
</body>

<script>
        function testmethod() {
            PageMethods.Test("Developer", onsuccess, onfail);
        }

        function onsuccess(res) {
            alert(res.d);
        }

        function onfail(res) {
            alert("error" + res);
        }
</script>
</html>
```

Code-behind C# :

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace HouseRentalPortal
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string Test(string name)
        {
            return "Welcome "+ name;
        }
    }
}
```

I just need to use the web method response in client side

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to check several things:

First, check in App_Start folder, that you comment out, or change this:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
```

To

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off; //<-- this
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
```

So, the redirect mode not really required if you have friendly URLs enabled, but you need to turn of that redirect mode.

Next up:

While a jQuery .ajax call should work, I find that page methods don't work UNLESS you turn off friendly URL's. However, you can "fix" this issue with this:

JavaScript:

```
PageMethods.set_path(PageMethods.get_path() + '.aspx');
```

So, just ensure above (JavaScript) line of code runs before using a Page Method.

Last but not least?

You MUST drop in a script manager to the web page, and you MUST add the enable page methods.

Hence this:

```
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
            runat="server"
            EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

   ... rest of your page follows....
```

So, taking all of above into account:

You checked/set in App_Start folder the RouteConfig.cs, and disabled redirect mode.

Hence this:

```
 settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;  <--- this
```

You have a script manager on the page, right after form tag, and enabled Page methods.

```
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
            runat="server"
            EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

And as noted, if friendly URLs are enabled, then you need this line of JavaScript code to run BEFORE you call the Page Method:

```
        PageMethods.set_path(PageMethods.get_path() + '.aspx');
```

So, then this markup:

```
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button"
                onclick="testmethod();return false;" />


        <script>

            PageMethods.set_path(PageMethods.get_path() + '.aspx');

            function testmethod() {
                PageMethods.Test("Developer", onsuccess, onfail);
            }

            function onsuccess(result) {
                alert(result);
            }

            function onfail(res, usercontext, methodname) {
                alert("error" + res);
            }
        </script>
```